# I couldn't run harm library on mac m1, there is following error message:

Tags: makefile

```
(base) user@Users-MBP src % make
mpic++ -O2 -Wno-unused-result -DMPI_USED -mfpmath=387 -I/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi -c  -o bounds.o bounds.c
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
error: unknown FP unit '387'
make: *** [bounds.o] Error 1
```

I think that I installed all required libraries

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html : "-mfpmath=unit ... '387' ... This is the default choice for non-Darwin x86-32 targets. ". M1 is not an x86-32 target; you'll need another option.

Comment: Note that MPI on macOS can be notoriously tricky.